# Report Content Overlapping

Tags: google-chrome, safari, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I'm new to reporting services and having trouble getting a report to render correctly on my ASPX page. I'm using **MS Report viewer 10 using with asp.net 4.0**

other than IE & Firefox, in all browsers content is overlapping[image].

Any suggestions appreciated!!

Comment: Have you checked your CSS? I'd assume it has to do with it and not actually the report viewer control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy crap.. resolved by created below script.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () { fixToolbar(); });

    function fixToolbar() {
        $("#ctl00_ReportViewer1_Toolbar table").each(function (i, item) {
            $(item).css('display', 'inline-block');
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried but the problem reoccurs when clicking on collapse toolbar button.